# VB.net manage opened excel file on the fly

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

In my current project, i need to modify an excel file that is already opened. That mean, i need to see the change in the excel file whenever i modify it.

Since opened file is locked and vb cannot access that file, my solution is to open another excel file, modify its content and then copy to the original file using excel vba, as excel vba can be used to copy data between opening sheets.

Here is the vb code in my other excel file (called TTHT.xlsm):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_CHANGE(ByVal Target As Range)
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  If Sheet1.[B5].Value = "#" Then
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  With Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\PCN.xlsm")
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TTHT").[B5]
        .Parent.Range("B4").Copy
        Sheets("PCN").[B4].PasteSpecial 7
        End With
    End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 End If
End Sub
```

Runs fine between my 2 opening excel file ( that TTHT one and PCN.xlsm ).

Now all I need to do, is to fill the data into TTHT, and put a "#" into B5 by my code. I think it will work, but it's not..

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    Dim oExcel As Object
    Dim oBook As Object
    Dim oSheet As Object
    oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
    oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(TTHTPath)
    oSheet = oBook.Worksheets("TTHT")
    oSheet.Range("B4").Value = txtValue_Needed.text
    oSheet.Range("B5").Value = "#"
    oBook.Save()
    'System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(DuongDanPhieuCongNghe)
    oSheet = Nothing
    oBook.Close()
    oBook = Nothing
    oExcel.Quit()
    oExcel = Nothing
End Sub
```

Result is, if i open the PCN file and click button, it won't change. If I close the PCN and click button, it will change..
But i need to see the change on the fly, not by close and reopen each time i need to update.
Can someone shed me some light, as to how, or which function ... either vba or vb.net, should i use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file is already opened and has focus then you can try looking it up in the running objects table.

```
Dim ExcelApplication As Excel.Application    
ExcelApplication = GetObject("C:\Folder\ExcelWorkbook.xls")
```

Then you can just make your modifications on the instance which you referenced while trying to avoid disrupting the user.

The getobject() function is great; here's a link.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e9waz863(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I am sorry I can't upvote your answer as my reputation is still very little :D 
Your solution of using GetObject is very simple yet it works perfect for me. 
Thank you very much.